# Java generics - passing arguments to generic method signatures

Tags: java, generics

I have the method below in my class

```
     public void doNothing(Map<String, Collection<? extends Number>> value) {

      }
```

and I'm calling this method with the parameter below.

```
    private void loader() {
       Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = null;
       doNothing(map);
    }
```

I get the error below.

```
   The method doNothing(Map<String,Collection<? extends Number>>) in the 
   type Lesson1<E> is not applicable for the arguments 
   (Map<String,ArrayList<Integer>>)
```

However if I changed the method to,

```
    public void doNothing(Collection<? extends Number> something) {

    }
```

and call it like below then there is no error.

```
    private void loader() {
        doNothing(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
```

Can someone help me the problem with using the first method which takes in a map as an argument?

Thanks!!!

Comment: `Map<String, ? extends Collection<? extends Number>>`

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer>` is a subclass of `Collection<Integer>` which is not the same as `Collection<? extends Number>`.